# crontab executing jar with properties files

Tags: ubuntu, properties, jar, terminal, cron

I'm trying to use crontab to execute a jar every minute.

This jar is working well if I execute it via Terminal. The point is that the jar reads some constants at execution time, from two java properties files situated in the same directory (same level than the jar).
The problem comes when I try to execute it via crontab, it doesn't works and I think it's probably because this properties files aren't found.

So... how can I set the path of this two properties files in the crontab 'code'?

my crontab 'code' till now:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=myuser@gmail.com
HOME=/

*/1 * * * * /usr/local/jdk/bin/java -jar /home/myuser/Desktop/Pre/myjar.jar
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: How are the property files read? Can you change the jar? Maybe the easiest solution would be to change the working directory like that: `cd /home/myuser/Desktop/Pre/ && /usr/local/jdk/bin/java -jar /home/myuser/Desktop/Pre/myjar.jar`

Comment: Hi @vstm, I'm going to try your solution.

I can change the jar because it's a java application made by me :) 
The jar is reading the properties file by using a Properties class in the java code : "java.util.Properties" with its methods

    properties.load(new FileInputStream(f)) 
and
    properties.getProperty(propertyname).